# How to inherit and modify the standard Django CMS Link plugin?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-cms

I've tried the following code:

cms_plugins.py:

```
from djangocms_link.cms_plugins import LinkPlugin
from .models import SecondaryNavigationLink

class SecondaryNavigationLinkPlugin(LinkPlugin):
    name = _("Secondary Navigation Link")
    model = SecondaryNavigationLink

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({
            'instance': instance,
            'placeholder': placeholder,
        })
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(SecondaryNavigationLinkPlugin)
```

models.py:

```
from djangocms_link.models import Link

class SecondaryNavigationLink(Link):
    pass
```

I can see my link plugin rendered on the cms control panel under Generic section, but as soon as I clicked save, I see a 500 interval server error from the request, and Django CMS renders a plugin block like this

```
Secondary Navigation Link <Empty>
```

And I cannot do anything about it.

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem, I shouldn't overwrite the render method

Comment: How can I close this question

Comment: You can answer it yourself and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I made a stupid mistake by overwriting the default render method of Link plugin:

https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/blob/master/djangocms_link/cms_plugins.py#L21

And this problem is fixed by simply get rid of my render function:

```
class SecondaryNavigationLinkPlugin(LinkPlugin):
    name = _("Secondary Navigation Link")
    model = SecondaryNavigationLink

    # No more render
```